# How to check IP Address changes in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How do I detect live IP Changes?

Example:

My ip without VPN: 3.3.3.3, whenever I connect to vpn my ip changes to 5.5.5.5.
My question is: How do I detect the IP has changed when the form is running?

I have tried:

```
Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
    Dim adapters As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    AddHandler NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged, AddressOf downloadip
    Dim n As NetworkInterface
    For Each n In adapters
        Timer4.Stop()
        Msgbox("IP Changed")          
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: I alread did it but it isn't working.

Comment: There is no IP change. You have *both* IPs, one is for your local network, the other is for the remote network. Your local adapter will still have its original IP. The VPN adapter will have the new one, as soon as it connects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, and you're saying whenever I connect to a VPN my IP doesn't change?

Comment: no, I say that you *local* IP doesn't change. Your IP on the remote network didn't even exist before connecting, or rather, you may have hade *some* hard-coded IP while disconnected, but if your VPN settings use DHCP, you'd get a new, valid remote IP as soon as the connection completed. Instead of looking for address changes, you should be looking for status changes on the VPN adapter

Comment: All I want to know is If there's a way to check whenever my external IP changes.

Comment: It doesn't. You have to detect when you actually connect to the remote network before trying to read the IP. Any value before that is bogus

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your IP on an external website

for example:

```
    Public Sub GetExternalIp()
            Try
                    Dim WithEvents IPBrowser As New WebBrowser
                    IPBrowser.Visible = False
                    Me.Controls.Add(IPBrowser)
                    IpBrowser.Navigate("http://seemyip.com/onyoursite.php")
            Catch
                Label2.Text = "failed to get external IP"
            End Try
    End Sub

       'then, put this OnNavigatingEvent
        If IpBrowser.Document.All("ip").GetAttribute("value") IsNot Nothing Then
             MyExtIp = IpBrowser.Document.All("ip").GetAttribute("value")
        Else
             MessageBox.Show("Can't find your IP")
        End If
```